# Configure ECS agent in jenkins without task definition

Tags: amazon-web-services, jenkins, amazon-ecs, agent

I want to configure ECS Cloud agent in Jenkins. But I don't want to use existing task definition instead I want to use my specific docker image. So when I trigger my pipeline it will build my job in ECS using the docker image I provided. When I am trying this with Jenkins/inbound-agent image it is building the job successfully in the ECS Cloud. But when I am trying to use another images it's not building.

I am using the following pipeline-
 `agent { ecs { cloud 'test_ecs'  // Reference to the ECS Cloud configuration you defined in Jenkins label 'test_ecs' launchType 'FARGATE' subnets 'subnet-12375ae4,subnet-123ed0cdc0' securityGroups 'sg-123a9b6f0ef313789' assignPublicIp true image 'jenkins/inbound-agent' memory '1024' cpu '256' }`
The above pipeline is working fine. But when I change the image to another then the build is not happening. I want to use my specific image which has dependencies required to build my job. So using my image I can build my Job in ECS. How can I do this. Can I?